Vuelidate is always fail on validation
So I have an a component with composable, one of them is modal, so the modal is only the canvas, I just pass the slot to the body, but when I do a create data, the vuelidate is always failing even though the data is filled.
I've tried to $v.$reset();it and it still error on validate
TestHoliday.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card w-full rounded-none border border-gray-300">
      <div
        class="card-body bg-gray-200 p-3 flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between"
      >
        <div class="mb-3 md:mb-0">
          <h3 class="text-xl font-bold text-primary flex justify-start">
            Holiday Table
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
          <button
            @click="openModal"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-white mb-2 md:mb-0 md:mr-2"
          >
            Add Holiday
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm text-white mb-2 md:mb-0 md:mr-2 w-full md:w-36"
            @click.prevent="generateHoliday"
            :disabled="stateLoading == true"
          >
            <div
              :class="
                stateLoading
                  ? 'loading loading-spinner loading-sm text-white'
                  : ''
              "
            >
              Generate Holiday
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card w-full bg-white rounded-none mb-5">
      <div class="card-body text-gray-700 p-3">
        <div class="overflow-x-auto">
          <TableManageHolidays></TableManageHolidays>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <Modal
      :isOpen="showModal"
      :isAlertExists="stateAlert"
      :alertMessage="alertMessage"
      @close="closeModal"
      @click.self="closeModal"
      @update:isAlertExists="updateAlertState"
    >
      <!-- Slot for header -->
      <template #header>{{ isEditing ? "Edit" : "Add" }} Holiday Date</template>
      <!-- Slot for body -->
      <template #body>
        <form
          id="holidayForm"
          @submit.prevent="submitData"
          class="mt-5 flex flex-col gap-5"
        >
          <div class="flex flex-col gap-2 form-control">
            <label for="name">Holiday Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              v-model="state.holiday.name"
              :class="{ invalid: v$.holiday.name.$error }"
              id="name"
              placeholder="Holiday Name"
              class="input input-bordered w-full"
              autofocus
            />
            <span v-if="v$.holiday.name.$error" class="text-sm text-red-500">{{
              v$.holiday.name.$errors[0].$message
            }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col gap-2 form-control">
            <label for="date">Holiday Date</label>
            <input
              type="date"
              v-model="state.holiday.date"
              :class="{ invalid: v$.holiday.date.$error }"
              id="date"
              placeholder="Holiday Date"
              class="input input-bordered w-full"
            />
            <span v-if="v$.holiday.date.$error" class="text-sm text-red-500">{{
              v$.holiday.date.$errors[0].$message
            }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col gap-2 form-control">
            <label for="description">Holiday Description</label>
            <textarea
              class="textarea textarea-bordered"
              v-model="state.holiday.description"
              id="description"
              placeholder="Holiday Description (Optional)"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="flex justify-end">
            <button
              type="submit"
              :class="isEditing ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-primary'"
              class="btn btn-primary w-full md:w-auto"
            >
              {{ isEditing ? "Save" : "Add" }} Holiday
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </template>
    </Modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useAdminStore } from "@/stores/admin";
import moment from "moment";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";
import { required } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import { computed, onMounted, reactive, ref } from "vue";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal.vue";
import TableManageHolidays from "@/components/admin/department,client/TableManageHolidays.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Modal,
    TableManageHolidays,
  },
  name: "ManageHolidays",
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      holiday: {
        name: "",
        date: "",
        description: "",
      },
    });
    const rules = computed(() => ({
      holiday: {
        name: { required },
        date: { required },
      },
    }));
    const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state);
    // const v$ = {
    //   $reset: () => {},
    //   $validate: async () => true,
    //   $errors: [],
    // };
    const admin = useAdminStore();

    const showModal = ref(false);

    // ? Alert
    const stateAlert = ref(false);
    const alertMessage = ref("");

    let holidays = ref([]);
    const stateLoading = ref(false);
    const isEditing = ref(false);
    const originalHoliday = ref({});
    const today = ref(new Date());

    const fetchHolidays = async () => {
      const data = await admin.fetchHolidays();
      const mappedHoliday = data.map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          date: moment(item.date).format("DD MMMM YYYY"),
        };
      });
      holidays.value = mappedHoliday;
      return mappedHoliday;
    };

    onMounted(async () => {
      await fetchHolidays();
    });

    return {
      fetchHolidays,
      admin,
      state,
      v$,
      holidays,
      stateLoading,
      isEditing,
      originalHoliday,
      alertMessage,
      today,
      stateAlert,
      showModal,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate(value) {
      return moment(value).format("DD MMMM YYYY");
    },
    updateAlertState(value) {
      this.stateAlert = value;
    },
    clearForm() {
      this.state.holiday = {
        name: "",
        date: "",
        description: "",
      };
      this.v$.$reset();
    },
    openModal() {
      this.clearForm();
      this.isEditing = false;
      this.showModal = true;
    },
    closeModal() {
      this.showModal = false;
    },
    closeAlert() {
      this.stateAlert = false;
    },
    async submitData() {
      if (this.isEditing) {
        await this.updateData();
      } else {
        await this.addData();
      }
    },
    async addData() {
      console.log("Holiday before validation:", this.state.holiday);
      this.v$.$reset();
      try {
        const isValid = await this.v$.$validate();
        console.log("Validation result:", isValid);
        if (!isValid) {
          console.error("Validation failed:", this.v$.$errors);
          return;
        }

        // Check if the data is exists
        const check = await this.admin.checkHolidayByDate(
          this.state.holiday.date
        );
        // console.log("check console :", check);
        // If the data exists then it will throuw status 200
        if (check.status == 200) {
          // Throw error that data is exists
          // Prevent any creating data with the same date
          throw new Error("Holiday Date already exist!");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.status == 404) {
          const response = await this.admin.addHoliday(this.state.holiday);

          // this.holidays = await this.admin.fetchHolidays();
          await this.fetchHolidays();
          // this.$refs.theModal.close();
          this.closeModal();
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Success...",
            text: response.data.message,
            timer: 2500,
          });
        } else {
          // this.$refs.theModal.showModal();
          this.openModal();
          this.stateAlert = true;
          this.alertMessage = error.message;
          return;
        }
      }
    },
    async editData(holiday) {
      try {
        this.clearForm();
        this.isEditing = true;
        const response = await this.admin.checkHolidayById(holiday.holiday_Id);
        response.date = response.date.split("T")[0];
        this.state.holiday = {
          ...response,
        };
        this.originalHoliday = {
          ...response,
        };
        // this.$refs.theModal.showModal();
        this.openModal();
        console.log("modal: ", showModal);
      } catch (error) {}
    },
    async updateData() {
      try {
        this.v$.$validate();

        if (this.v$.$error) {
          return;
        }

        // Check for changes in data
        if (
          this.state.holiday.name === this.originalHoliday.name &&
          this.state.holiday.date === this.originalHoliday.date &&
          this.state.holiday.description === this.originalHoliday.description
        ) {
          this.stateAlert = true;
          this.alertMessage = "No changes detected!";
          return;
        }
        const response = await this.admin.updateHoliday(this.state.holiday);

        // this.holidays = await this.admin.fetchHolidays();
        await this.fetchHolidays();
        this.closeModal();
        await Swal.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "Success...",
          text: response.data.message,
          timer: 2500,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        this.$refs.theModal.showModal();
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Error...",
          text: error.data.message,
          timer: 2500,
        });
      }
    },
    async deleteData(id) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Apa anda yakin?",
        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
      }).then(async (result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          try {
            const response = await this.admin.deleteHoliday(id);
            Swal.fire({
              title: "Success...",
              text: response.data.message,
              icon: "success",
              timer: 2500,
            });
            // this.holidays = await this.admin.fetchHolidays();
            await this.fetchHolidays();
          } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: "error",
              title: "Error...",
              text: error.data.message,
              timer: 2500,
            });
          }
        }
      });
    },
    async generateHoliday() {
      this.stateLoading = true;
      let totalSuccessInsert = 0;
      let totalFailedInsert = 0;
      let totalExistingDate = 0;

      try {
        const googleHoliday = await this.admin.fetchGoogleHoliday();
        const promises = googleHoliday.map(async (data) => {
          try {
            await this.admin.checkHolidayByDate(data.date);
            totalExistingDate += 1;
          } catch (error) {
            if (error.status === 404) {
              const newHoliday = {
                name: data.name,
                date: data.date,
                description: null,
              };

              try {
                await this.admin.addHoliday(newHoliday);
                totalSuccessInsert += 1;
              } catch (error) {
                totalFailedInsert += 1;
              }
            } else {
              totalFailedInsert += 1;
            }
          }
        });
        await Promise.all(promises);

        this.stateLoading = false;
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Holiday Generated!",
          html: `${totalSuccessInsert} Berhasil, ${totalFailedInsert} Gagal, ${totalExistingDate} Telah Ada`,
          icon: "info",
        });

        await this.fetchHolidays();
      } catch (error) {
        this.stateLoading = false;
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Error",
          text: "Failed to fetch holiday data. Please try again.",
          icon: "error",
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
</style>

Modal.vue
<template>
  <div
    v-if="isOpen"
    class="fixed inset-0 p-8 overflow-auto h-full bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 flex items-center justify-center z-50"
  >
    <dialog id="theModal" ref="theModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-box">
        <form method="dialog">
          <button
            @click="closeModal"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-circle btn-ghost absolute right-2 top-2"
          >
            ✕
          </button>
        </form>
        <h3 class="text-lg font-bold">
          <slot name="header">Default Modal Title</slot>
        </h3>
        <div v-if="isAlertExists">
          <!-- Alert Section -->
          <div
            role="alert"
            class="alert alert-warning mb-4 flex items-center justify-between mt-3"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0 stroke-current"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              >
                <path
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.333.192 3 1.732 3z"
                />
              </svg>
              Warning: {{ alertMessage }}
            </div>
            <!-- Close Alert Button -->
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-circle btn-ghost" @click="closeAlert">
              ✕
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <slot name="body"> </slot>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="dialog" class="modal-backdrop">
        <button @click="closeModal">close</button>
      </form>
    </dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { nextTick, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    isOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    isAlertExists: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    alertMessage: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    // console.log(props.isAlertExists);
    const showAlert = ref(true);

    return { showAlert };
  },
  watch: {
    isOpen(newVal) {
      nextTick(() => {
        if (newVal) {
          this.$refs.theModal.showModal();
        }
      });
    },
  },

  methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.$emit("close");
      this.$refs.theModal.close();
    },
    closeAlert() {
      // this.showAlert = false;
      this.$emit("update:isAlertExists", false);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Optional custom styling */
</style>

Just ignore the table component, the problem is on the addData() function that has vuelidate is not working properly
Edit:
here is the response of the failed validation

the vuelidation detected that the text input is empty so it throws required invalid,
$message :  "Value is required" $params :  {type: 'required'}

Please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged

by fail, do you mean const isValid = await this.v$.$validate(); is false? in that case, what is the output of console.error("Validation failed:", this.v$.$errors);

edited, there I put the image of the error of the console.error

@EstusFlask , basically its just a component with modal with form as its slot, but the form in the modal is just always error to validate the  text input, vuelidate always returns error message as "Value is required" although the text input is populated with data
